# Safari on iPhone: Can I close the oauth browser tab?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, passbook

I am using oauth to authenticate my iPhone-app's users. They click the login button and Safari opens to display the password entry page. Afterwards they are redirected using a custom url scheme, e.g. myapp://somethingsomething, which opens the application again (sending Safari into the background).

Can I close the browser tap during that redirect? Or directly afterwards via Javascript?

I ask because if my user imports a bording pass to his Passbook, Safari opens and logs my user in again, since the tab was still there.

Answer (score 2):

Ok fixed by doing a setTimeout() call in JS before issuing the redirect. In the setTimeout() another redirect is executed: To a harmless page.